# The requested registry access is invalid

Tags: powershell, scripting, registry

I'm a learning System engineer and I have to Script a PowerShell Script who simply creates a Registry Key and a Value in it. I can't get it right, there is always this weird error popping up. Likewise, I already tried running it as an Administrator. Please Help!

Translation of the Error.
“The requested registry access is invalid.”

Script:

$regkey="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Reporting"

$regparam="DisableEnhancedNotifications"

cd HKLM:\

New-ItemProperty -Path "$regkey" -Name "$regparam" -Value "test" -PropertyType "String"

Thanks!

Comment: To alter things in the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` hive you need to run PowerShell as Administrator. Not only that, but the syntax you use is wrong: either use `Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Reporting` or use the PowerShell drive syntax `HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Reporting`

Answer (score 0):

```
$regkey='HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Reporting'
$regparam='DisableEnhancedNotifications'

# create key
New-Item -Path $regkey -Force

# create entry
New-ItemProperty -Path $regkey -Name $regparam -PropertyType String -Value 'test' -Force
```

more examples: [Working with Registry Entries (learn.microsoft.com)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/working-with-registry-entries?view=powershell-7.2#creating-new-registry-entries)